# Run code once Spring app is successfully deployed

Tags: spring, events, spring-mvc, listener

Is there a way in a Spring app to know when the initialization has finished? I have to run some code once my app is deployed and I'm searching something like ServletContextListener or [Spring built-in events](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm).

Comment: Do you need the entire app initialized, or just a specific bean initialized?

Comment: Indeed I just need a connection with the embedded DB to add some records. So, an autowired instance of one of my services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment I will respond with the multiple things you can do to process an initialized Spring bean.

1. You can utilize a [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html).  It has two methods that are treated as callbacks, and I believe that [`postProcessAfterInitialization`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html#postProcessAfterInitialization%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) is the one that you would be interested in.  The thing with `BeanPostProcessor`'s is that they are run for each bean in the `ApplicationContext`, so you will want to be sure to look for only the bean(s) that you are interested in applying this processing to.  To use a `BeanPostProcessor`, you simply define it as a part of your `ApplicationContext`.
2. Implement the [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface.  It defines a single method [`afterPropertiesSet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29) which is invoked by the `ApplicationContext`.  This has an advantage over number 1, as it can be applied on a bean by bean basis (doesn't apply to all beans in `ApplicationContext`).
3. Utilize the [`@PostContstuct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation on a method.  This annotation tells the `ApplicationContext` that this method should be run after the bean has been initialized.  This acts similarly to number 2, in that it is performed on a bean by bean basis.

Further information on the callback lifecycle of the `ApplicationContext` can be read about at [this location](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle).

Comment: Actually I don't have a bean. I just want to set some DB records once the database connection is established. I could define a Service or a Component but after set this records I don't need the Service/Component and I don't know if it is a good idea to keep it there lying around. What would be the best option to do this?

Comment: You could create a bean whose sole function is to perform this operation.  That is what I would do.

Comment: Yes, I think that it's the best option. Can I remove the instance after execute it or is not necessary?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to remove it after.  Its presence shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: But I suppose that the bean will be consuming resources (memory mainly). Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: The memory consumed by this would be so minuscule that you wouldn't even notice it.  I think your time would be better spent working on other potential memory issues within your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [`@PostConstruct`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation
- or a [`ApplicationListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) that get triggered by the [`ContextStartedEvent`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html) (but take care if you have a typical web application you have two contexts and so two `ContextStartedEvent`s.

Comment: I thought that ContextStartedEvent was launched once the app starts to deploy. I'll try it. Just one question. I have the the main context and root-context, how can I differenciate them? Hibernate connection is defined in root-context.

Comment: I've been searching about ContextStartedEvent and I've read that this event is published when the ApplicationContext is started using the start() so I can't use it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why you cant use it? You wrote: "..when the initialization has finished?" -- that should be the the point where "ContextStartEvent" is raised.

Comment: Yes, but I have to run start method implicitly. That's not the case.

Comment: You have an explanation about what I'm saying here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?85281-Difference-between-ContextStartedEvent-amp-ContextRefreshedEvent

Comment: You do not need to invoke any thing, at least not in a Web Application. Belive me, try it, almost all of my Web Applications use this event and I have never ever invoked any method in order to "start" it.